# tops command giving error when executed through NSTask

Tags: cocoa, nstask

I am trying to use below **tops** command through NSTask:

```
tops replace "__My_CompanyName__" with "XYZ" TryItOut.m
```

but it is always giving below error:

```
File replace "__My_CompanyName__" with "XYZ" does not exist
```

When executed through terminal it works fine.

Below is the code, which I used:

```
NSTask *theTopsCommand = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[theTopsCommand setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/tops"];
[theTopsCommand setArguments:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"replace \"__My_CompanyName__\" with \"XYZ\"", self.selectedFilePath,nil]];
[theTopsCommand launch];
[theTopsCommand waitUntilExit];
```

Can anyone suggest me, if I did anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the arguments to `tops` as an array of strings, but you are providing one single string.

Try:

```
[theTopsCommand setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"replace", @"__My_CompanyName__", @"with", @"XYZ", self.selectedFilePath, nil]];
```